# android thread while loop not running well

Tags: android, multithreading

this is my thread:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Log.d("ConnectionThread","Starting Server Connection");
        try {
            while(isThereActivityRunning()) {
                if(isInternetOn == true){
                    Log.d("ConnectionThread", "Internet is On. Sending Http request");
                    results = sendGetMessage();
                    b.putString("results", results);
                    receiver.send(2, b);
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("ConnectionThread","Internet is Off. Sleeping");
                }
                ConnectionThread.sleep(timeInterval);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            results = e.toString();
        }
    Log.d("ConnectionThread","Server Connection Finished");
    }
```

The `isInternetOn` `boolean` is from an event listener I've made, and it's value is changed by the state of the internet.

For some reason when the internet is on `(isInternetOn == true)` it does the if condition and then go to the else condition..

I can't figure out why it is doing this.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the if condition isn't executed once, followed by the sleep, followed by a new loop iteration where it skips the if and goes to the else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I am parsing your question correctly but you need to make sure that the values that you are checking inside of `isThereActivityRunning()` have been marked as `volatile` or have been `synchronized` if it is accessed in multiple threads.  Same goes for `isInternetOn`.  If your thread is not seeing this value change and if it is changed by another thread then this is probably the issue.  You can also use the `AtomicBoolean` and other classes to share values between threads.

Comment: i can't volatile a boolean function. this function check if there's any activity running and if not, it stops the while loop which will cause to stop the thread

Comment: and i only have this thread running...
and i have declared private volatile boolean isInternetOn;

Comment: @AsafNevo Right I changed my answer to take into account the method.

Comment: @AsafNevo I still don't understand the problem.  Can you edit your question and add more details about how your loop is executing?

Comment: sure.
this thread job is to connect a remote server with http request, and to send the response to the activity sent it.
the isThereActivityRunning() check if there are activities on board, in order to stop this thread when the user ends the application.
i have the boolean isInternetOn which is updated throw an event listener i've built, and supposed to reflect the state of the internet.
when i'm turning the internet off everything is ok and i see in the log that the internet is off.

Comment: when i'm turning it back on - i can see that the internet is on, and then after it logging - "internet is on" it says - "internet is Off"..
it's really weird as if it doesn't consider the if condition...

Comment: @AsafNevo  Maybe there is a bug in the code that is detecting the state of the internet?  You should log that value in this thread and the detector thread.  Also you should log if you are getting a `InterruptedException` as opposed to catching it and ignoring it.

Comment: Since you're apparently without a debugger, I guess we can only make things up... it sounds race-induced. Try initializing it to false and limited the places where the variable is modified to one. Then, determine what is causing the value change.

Comment: i will try although it weird. there supposed to be 10 seconds sleeping time after each if condition...
i get the internet on and internet off logging in less then 10 seconds, like it does them both..

Comment: @AsafNevo You sure it is 10000 millis or just 10.  Thread.sleep(long) takes millis right?  :-)

Comment: yeah :) what's really weird that before i did the internet on check with other method, and now that i was finally able to register listeners for the internet state - it gives me hard time inside the loop :)